# Xcode add to project is empty

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I have created a project with the following command line:

```
swift package init --type executable
```

Afterwards, I would like to add a library to the project via `xcode`. Unfortunately, it shows an empty field in the **Add to project** so I can not add it to the project:

[image]

How to make the project visible in the `Add to Project` dropdown list?

The content of the `Package.swift` file

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "redix-svc-test",
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package, defining a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package and products from dependencies.
        .executableTarget(
            name: "redix-svc-test")
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't, at least not in the current version of Xcode. That dropdown is for projects generated by Xcode, like frameworks and apps.

Instead, you're supposed to press Copy dependency, which copies a dependency declaration onto the clipboard, which you then manually add to your Package.swift.

Of course, don't forget to declare the executable target's dependency either.

E.g.:

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "redix-svc-test",
    dependencies: [
        // this is the line Xcode copied
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/websocket-kit", .upToNextMajor(from: "2.0.0")),
    ],
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "redix-svc-test",
            // and this is what you must come up with yourself
            dependencies: [.product(name: "WebSocketKit", package: "websocket-kit")]),
    ]
)
```